# Go multi level priority queue

Tags: algorithm, go, multidimensional-array, priority-queue

In Go, the `container/heap` package can be used as a PriorityQueue --
https://pkg.go.dev/container/heap#example-package-PriorityQueue

Is there any Go package for multi level priority queue? If not, how to write one myself?

By "multi level priority queue", here is what I mean:

- Task 1: run through all marks from students, and get the top N students with highest marks. This is typical PriorityQueue.
- Task 2: run through all marks from students of different courses, and get the top N  highest marks for top N course (assuming the number of courses is greater than N). This is the *"multi level priority queue"* that I'm talking about.

Sample result can be

```
course A: 99 98 98 
course B: 92 90 88
course C: 91 89 87
```

Notes,

1. `course D:` with top 3 highest marks of `90 89 88` are not in top 3 courses.
2. There might be cases that there isn't enough students marks to fill all top N highest marks. E.g.:

   ```
   course E: 85 82
   course F: 83
   course G: 82 80 78
   ```
3. Further on the requirements, In reality,

   - the data come from parsing a super complicated and super large XML file, thus I need to walk the XML file in a *single pass*, that's why I need the priority queue.
   - the XML file is actually SQL Server Trace file, which contains hundreds or even thousands of SQL commands (the SQL commands being the courses, and their duration being course marks), that's the second reason that I need the priority queue -- to track only the top ones.

Comment: What defines the “top N courses”?

Comment: Courses ranked/ordered by the top mark they get, then get the top N of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any sort of exotic queue structure to solve it. You don't even need a priority queue at all, though it's a simple way to do the select-k operation. (If you don't need your outputs to be sorted relative to each other but just be the top N in *some* order, it's more efficient to use a selection algorithm like quickselect.)

For task 2, you simply need to iterate through all marks, building the top mark for each course. Once you've done that, you find the top N courses. Once you've done that, iterate through all marks again, filtering the ones for those courses into separate containers. Then just do a select-k in each one.

The running time of this approach is `O(m + N^2 log N)` (where `m` is the total number of marks) if you use a priority queue, and `O(m + N^2)` if you use an efficient selection algorithm. The latter time bound is the best possible for the problem, because `O(m)` inputs need to be examined and `O(N^2)` outputs need to be generated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sneftel.  I forgot to stress one thing (and now I've updated the OP) -- _"In reality, the data come from parsing a super complicated and super large XML file, thus I need to walk the XML file in a single pass, that's why I need the priority queue."_ Also, for the select-k operation, per your suggestion, I found a Go selection algorithm of quickselect at https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/wangjohn/quickselect, which a third party package, while the container/heap package is a native one, which is available out of the box.

Comment: Over all, the data come in a stream, If you can give a single pass solution, please keep this good answer and give another solution. thx.

Comment: The online (streamed) solution would be to keep separate priority queues (of max size N) for *all* courses, then select the top N courses afterwards. There's no way to do it with additional size less than `O(c*N)`.

Comment: Thanks for providing the all those alternative solutions. The second reason that I need the priority queue is that _"the XML file is actually SQL Server Trace file, which contains hundreds or even thousands of SQL commands"_ -- i.e., I just want to track only the top ones instead of all of them.

Comment: The storage of "thousands of SQL commands" is trivial if you simply parse the XML file up front. Don't make the problem harder than you have to.

Comment: Indeed, no need to make the problem harder. this is not what I had been looking for but definitely what I can accept. thx!